# TimePickerDialog in a ListAdapter: Fragment already added

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialogfragment

I have a list which rows are created dynamically. Each row contains a EditText and when the user clicks on this view I want a TimePickerDialog to show up. I'm using the same technique somewhere else in my code, but not in a ListView, and it works perfectly, but somehow at this point I always get

```
ERROR   AndroidRuntime      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: TimePickerDialogFragment{42f06710 #0 0c005225-d6a4-47f9-b3ee-ac90a70d3962}
ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1175)
ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:616)
```

My ListAdapter is:

```
private class SetAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;        

        public SetAdapter() {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(TrainingDetailActivity.this);
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.training_detail_row, parent, false);
            EditText col1 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.trainingDetailCol1);
            setTimePickerTo(col1, exercise.getSets().get(position), UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        }
}
```

and

```
private void setTimePickerTo(EditText editText, final Set set, final String tag) {
        int hours = exercise.getDuration() / 60;
        int minutes = exercise.getDuration() % 60;
        editText.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", hours, minutes));
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerDurationListener
            = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    int val = hourOfDay * 60 + minute;
                    exercise.setDuration(val);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            };
        final TimePickerDialogFragment timePickerDuration
                = new TimePickerDialogFragment(exercise, timePickerDurationListener);
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    timePickerDuration.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), tag);
                }
                else {

                }
            }
        });

    }
```

So as the TimePickerDialogFragment works somewhere else I guess the problem comes from the ListView. If I add a

```
timePickerDuration.dismiss()
```

to the else-case on onFocusChange(), the dialog shows and dismisses several times and logcat gets spammed with

```
WARN    IInputConnectionWrapper getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
WARN    IInputConnectionWrapper getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
WARN    IInputConnectionWrapper getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
```

Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: In the adapter class, in getView(), put an `if (convertView == null)` condition surrounding the  `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.training_detail_row, parent, false);`

Comment: Try putting     `final TimePickerDialogFragment timePickerDuration
                = new TimePickerDialogFragment(exercise, timePickerDurationListener);` in the onFocusChange() method. Right now you are creating a fragment for each row unnecessarily when it should only be created when you need it.

Comment: That seems to help, although I don't get what's the big difference. However, the dialog shows up twice, now, what I fixed by simply using an OnTouchListener, so thanks for your help.